# How can I retrieve multiple JSON files using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a web application that receives json from a server. I was using this code:

```
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "url where I have the json"
http_request.onreadystatechange = handle_json;
http_request.open("GET", url, true);
http_request.send(null);
var obj;

function handle_json() {
if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
if (http_request.status == 200) {
     var json_data = http_request.responseText; 
     obj = eval("(" + json_data + ")");
     processData(obj);

} else {
  alert("A problem ocurred");
}
http_request = null;
```

}
}

But now I want to receive json from two url's and show the information. How can I do this using JavaScript? I know eval is not the appropiate thing to do but this is just a prototype.

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Fyi, you should use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()` to parse JSON. Is using jQuery an option? It would turn your code pretty much into a one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you simply need to make 2 requests. In order to re-use the code you have already written, you could define a function to get json that takes a url argument. Something like this:

```
function getJson(url, callback){
  function handle_json() {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
      if (http_request.status == 200) {
        var json_data = http_request.responseText;
        var parser = (JSON && typeof JSON.parse == 'function') ? JSON.parse : eval;
        var obj = parser("(" + json_data + ")");
        callback(obj);
      } else {
        alert("A problem ocurred");
      }
      http_request = null;
    }
  }

  var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http_request.onreadystatechange = handle_json;
  http_request.open("GET", url, true);
  http_request.send(null);
}
```

I replaced the call to eval with some logic that will call `JSON.parse` if it is present, otherwise it will use `eval`. Using this function would allow you to make multiple requests by calling it multiple times, like so:

```
getJson("some url", processData);
getJson("some other url", processData");
```

If you wanted to process data from different urls in different ways, just define another function similar to `processData` and pass it along instead, like `getJson("some crazy url", processCrazyData);`

Using a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would reduce the amount of code that you have to write, but this solution should get it done using basic javascript.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to put it into a function.

```
function getJson(url) {
    //Remove the var url="string" line
    //Rest of code
}

function handleJson() {
    //Other code
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [jQuery](http://jquery.org), in which case your code would be:

```
$.getJSON('url goes in here',function(data){
    processData(data);
});
```

And just use that whenever you want to grab a page.